# Array in dictionary in Sharepoint Designer Workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want to add an item with a "PostCategory" multiple lookup value in Sharepoint Workflow 2013 and Sharepoint Designer.

Here the request:

`POST /_api/lists/getbytitle('Billets')/items`

```
{
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.BilletsListItem" },
    "Title": "TEST",
    "PublishedDate": "2016-05-06T10:52:00Z",
    "Body": "test",
    "PostCategoryId": {"results": [2]}
}
```

This request works perfectly with Postman and Fiddler software.

I want to implement this in Sharepoint Designer like this :

- postCategories dictionary

[image: postCategories]

- postData dictionary

[image: postData]

The json generated is :

```
{
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.BilletsListItem" },
    "Title": "Mise à jour",
    "PublishedDate": "2016-05-06T10:52:00Z",
    "Body": "<p>Une mise à jour...</p>",
    "PostCategoryId": {"results": "[2]"}
}
```

The result of this request is BadRequest.
Sharepoint Designer add quotes around the Array (`"[2]"` instead of `[2]`).

Are there has a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great solution is posted in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/44b7aa5d-2553-4af9-ba8a-64447eb80b55/is-there-a-way-to-build-a-json-array-in-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required). Check Miroslav Kapounek answer.

This solution in other words:

1. Create string variable `tempJsonString` with correctly formatted JSON string, like `{"results": [2]}`
2. Build dictionary. Add new value and choose type `Dictionary`. Then in value selection select your string variable `tempJsonString`. Check that value selector in SharePoint Designer shows *Return result as*: **As Dictionary from JSON**